# Using AVPlayer.currentItem?.asset.duration makes UI stop for some duration

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avplayer

I have a function that plays a song with the url i have given in it's parameters. I am using AVPlayer to do this.

```
      func playSong(url:URL) {
        self.playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
        self.avPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
        self.avPlayer.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = false
        self.avPlayer!.volume = 1.0
        self.avPlayer.play()
        let duration = (self.avPlayer.currentItem?.asset.duration)!
        let totalDuration : CMTime = duration
        let seconds : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(totalDuration)
        self.totalAudioPlaybackTime.text = self.stringFromTimeInterval(interval: seconds)
        self.sliderProgress.maximumValue = Float(seconds)
        self.timeObserver = self.avPlayer.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTime.init(value: 1, timescale: 1), queue: .main, using: { time in
            if let duration = self.avPlayer.currentItem?.duration{
                let time : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.avPlayer!.currentTime())
                self.sliderProgress.value = Float(time)
                self.currentTime.text = self.stringFromTimeInterval(interval: time)
                }
            })
    }
```

Everything else is working fine but the only issue is at the line

```
         let duration = (self.avPlayer.currentItem?.asset.duration)!
```

When ever this line is executed it takes 5 to 6 seconds(sometimes even 10) to calculate the duration and while that is happening the UI just freezes until the duration is calculated. I have no idea why that is happening. Kindly let me know what i am doing wrong

Comment: what if you call it from the main queue?

Comment: @Asteroid You mean inside DispatchQueue.main.async? I tried it but that didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You should load `duration` from the background thread.

You can use the new swift concurrency

```
Task {
    let duration = try await asset.load(.duration)
}
```

Apple Docs:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_assets/loading_media_data_asynchronously